# List of time from 12 am to 12 am

Tags: php

I want to print time from `00:00` to `23.30` with interval of `15 minute`. Like `00.00`, `00.15`, `00.30` and so on . How can I do it ?

Can anyone help me please?

Code :

```
<table border=2>
<?php
$time = 23;
$k=0;     
 for ($i = 12; $i <= $time; $i++) {
        for ($min = 0; $min < 2; $min++) {
            ?>
            <tr>           
                <td><?php
                    if (($min % 2) == 0) {
                        if (strlen($i) == 1)
                            echo $str1 =  "0" . $i . ":00";
                        else
                            echo $str1 = $i . ":00";
                    }else{
                    if (strlen($i) == 1)
                        echo $str1 = "0" . $i . ":30";
                    else
                       echo  $str1 = $i . ":30";}}}
                    ?></td></tr>
```

It is giving me output for every 30 minute.I want to change this in to every 15 minute with `same logic`.How can I do that ?

Comment: Do you understand the code you posted?

Comment: Is anything wrong in code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try if you want from 00:00 start `$i = 0`

```
<?php
$time = 23;
$k=0;     
 for ($i = 12; $i <= $time; $i++) {
        for ($min = 0; $min < 4; $min++) {
            ?>
            <tr>           
                <td><?php
                    if (($min % 4) == 0) {
                        if (strlen($i) == 1)
                            echo $str1 =  "0" . $i . ":00";
                        else
                            echo $str1 = $i . ":00";
                    }
                    elseif (($min % 3) == 0) {
                        if (strlen($i) == 1)
                            echo $str1 =  "0" . $i . ":45";
                        else
                            echo $str1 = $i . ":45";
                    }
                    elseif (($min % 2) == 0) {
                        if (strlen($i) == 1)
                            echo $str1 =  "0" . $i . ":30";
                        else
                            echo $str1 = $i . ":30";
                    }

                    else{
                    if (strlen($i) == 1)
                        echo $str1 = "0" . $i . ":15";
                    else
                       echo  $str1 = $i . ":15";}}}
                    ?>
```

Answer (score 11):

```
    $time = new \DateTime("midnight");
    $endTime = new \DateTime("midnight tomorrow");

    echo "<table border=2>";
    while ($time < $endTime) {
        echo "<tr><td>" . $time->format("H:i") . "</td></tr>";
        $time->modify("+15 minutes");
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

It's cleaner, shorter, and FAR easier to modify.

Comment: "+1" thats a beauty !

Comment: Very nice answer and style

Comment: @RakeshSharma, if `$time = new \DateTime("noon");` it will print from *12:00* to *24:00* as OP's logic in question!! This is far better way to code!!

Comment: @ShaunakShukla yeah i know. you can which answer accepting

Comment: There's no real difference between the functionalities of mine and hers; this is just written more cleanly. But she still accepted yours, so apparently she did very specifically want it to look that way.(no idea why, but it's their code, so hey. At least now when other people want to do this kind of thing, they can also see there's an easier way :) )

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
$start_time = "00:00:00";
$end_time = "23:45:00";
echo "<table>";
for($time = strtotime($start_time); $time <= strtotime($end_time);  $time += 900) {
?>
     <tr><td><?php echo date("H:i",$time)."<br/>";?></td></tr>
<?php }
echo "</table>";
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

My attempt, which was just tidying up the existing logic:

```
<?php

$time = 23;
$k = 0;  // not used anywhere?   
$mins = [0, 15, 30, 45];

for ($i = 12; $i <= $time; $i++) {
    for ($min = 0; $min <= 60; $min++) {
        ?>
        <tr>           
            <td>
                <?php
                    if (in_array($min, $mins)) {
                       echo $str1 = str_pad($i, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT) . ":" . str_pad($min, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
                    }

    }
}

?>
```

So you can just modify the array if you want to add in any more times and also using `str_pad` so that the hours and minutes are zero-padded which removes the need for a few of the `if` statements.

Should also probably move the `in_array` check to outside the `tr` to avoid creating 56 blank rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table border=2>
    <?php
    $time = 23;
    for ($i = 12; $i <= $time; $i++) {
        for ($min = 0; $min < 4; $min++) {
            ?>
            <tr>           
                <td>
                    <?php
                    switch ($min) {
                        case '0': echo $i . ':00';
                            break;
                        case '1': echo $i . ':15';
                            break;
                        case '2': echo $i . ':30';
                            break;
                        case '3': echo $i . ':45';
                            break;
                    }
                    ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table border=2>
<?php
$time = 23;
$k=0;     
 for ($i = 12; $i <= $time; $i++) {
        for ($min = 0; $min < 4; $min++) {
            ?>
            <tr>           
                <td><?php
                    if (($min % 4) == 0) {
                        if (strlen($i) == 1)
                            echo $str1 =  "0" . $i . ":00";
                        else
                            echo $str1 = $i . ":00";
                    }else if (($min % 4) == 1){
                        if (strlen($i) == 1)
                            echo $str1 = "0" . $i . ":15";
                        else
                           echo  $str1 = $i . ":15";
                    }else if (($min % 4) == 2){
                        if (strlen($i) == 1)
                            echo $str1 = "0" . $i . ":30";
                        else
                           echo  $str1 = $i . ":30";
                    }else{
                        if (strlen($i) == 1)
                            echo $str1 = "0" . $i . ":45";
                        else
                           echo  $str1 = $i . ":45";
                    }


                    }}
                    ?>
</td></tr>
```

Comment: Could you add a few lines to explain your solution ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt

```
<table border=2>
<?php
$h = 0;
$m = 0;
while($h <= 23)
{
    while($m < 60)
    {
        $hour = sprintf('%02d',$h);
        $minute = sprintf('%02d',$m);
        print "<tr><td>$hour:$minute</td></tr>";
        $m += 15;
    }
    $m = 0;
    $h++;
}
?>
```